# Why is my small font too blurry on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, fonts

I am porting a game from the iPad to iPhone (using XCode cocos+box). I use a custom font (*.ttf) which is nice when drawn with a big font size, but if I use a small font size, the text gets too blurry.

If I do not scale font size itself but scale the font's parent, the text becomes too sharp-cut and memory consuming. Since I'm porting a game, I need font to be a bit blurry, but not too much so that it is still readable.

There is also another problem with the blurriness: not all text looks nice. I create a "Start game" label and it looks just fine but when I create a "Settings" label just the same way it looks more blurry.

Is it because of the *.ttf file or is it me doing something wrong? If it is the font, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text and images look blurry if they are drawn at half pixel boundaries, can you provide us with the source code that is responsible for drawing the text into the screen?

Comment: Yeh thank you! I do create a text like _totalScoreLabel = [CCLabel labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total scores: $0"] fontName:FONT_NAME fontSize:((int)(25*kw))]; I did calculate the size for iphone 3 and it is 12, did put it in instead of ((int)(25*kw)) and the text did become better but i wonder why doesn't it trunc properly that way as it is?